# extract different lines from files using Bash

Tags: bash, comm

I have two files and I use the "comm -23 file1 file2" command to extract the lines that are different from a file to another.

I would also need something that extracts the different lines but also preserves the string "line_$NR". 
Example:
file1:

```
line_1: This is line0
line_2: This is line1
line_3: This is line2
line_4: This is line3
```

file2:

```
line_1: This is line1
line_2: This is line2
line_3: This is line3
```

I need this output:
differences file1 file2:

```
line_1: This is line0.
```

In conclusion I need to extract the differences as if the file has not line_$NR at the beginning but when I print the result I need to also print line_$NR.

Comment: I want a sort of diff between the files but without comparing line_NR, only print line_NR. I don't know if comm is appropriate.

Comment: Your version of `diff` may have options for producing `comm`-like side-by-side output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `awk`

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR {a[$2]; next} !($2 in a)' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
line_1: This is line0
```

**Short Description**

```
awk -F: '             # Set filed separator as ':'. $1 contains line_<n> and $2 contains 'This is line_<m>'
    NR==FNR {         # If Number of records equal to relative number of records, i.e. first file is being parsed
        a[$2];        # store $2 as a key in associative array 'a'
        next          # Don't process further. Go to next record.
    } 
    !($2 in a)        # Print a line if $2 of that line is not a key of array 'a'
' file2 file1
```

---

**Additional Requirement** (*In comment*)

> And if I have multiple ":" in a line : "line_1: This :is: line0"
>   doesn't work. How can I only take the line_x

In that case, try following (**GNU awk** only)

```
awk -F'line_[0-9]+:' 'NR==FNR {a[$2]; next} !($2 in a)' file2 file1
```

Comment: this command fails if the "difference" locates in file2.  in another word, if both files had "difference" the awk approach in anwer won't work.

Comment: @Kent Agree. But this solution was based on OP's command `comm -23 file1 file2` where I believe it means the lines unique to **file1**. Correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: It is right. Actually I need a sort of diff between file1 and file2. I was using comm  -23 file1 file2 and comm -23 file2 file1

Comment: @georgiana_e then you are looking for `comm -2`. In that case `diff` is better command. Bdw if you just want to follow your approach, then can't you apply the same logic to my solution by swapping file1 and file2?

Comment: Seems to work your solution but could you please explain a little bit. I don't understand what it is doing.

Comment: And if I have multiple ":" in a line : "line_1: This :is: line0" doesn't work. How can I only take the line_x.

Comment: @georgiana_e Please check updated answer for both explanation and solution for multiple ':'

Answer (score 0):

this awk line is longer, however it would work no matter where the differences were located:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$NF]=$0;next}a[$NF]{a[$NF]=0;next}7;END{for(x in a)if(a[x])print a[x]}' file1 file2
```

test:

```
kent$  head f*
==> f1 <==
line_1: This is line0
line_2: This is line1
line_3: This is line2
line_4: This is line3

==> f2 <==
line_1: This is line1
line_2: This is line2
line_3: This is line3

#test f1 f2
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$NF]=$0;next}a[$NF]{a[$NF]=0;next}7;END{for(x in a)if(a[x])print a[x]}' f1 f2
line_1: This is line0

#test f2 f1:    
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$NF]=$0;next}a[$NF]{a[$NF]=0;next}7;END{for(x in a)if(a[x])print a[x]}' f2 f1
line_1: This is line0
```

Comment: And I I want to do diff between file1 file2 without the line_$NR then insert line_$NR using awk?

Comment: I don't want that test f2 f1 return the same output as test f1 f2. Also in file 2 I changed "This is line 2" with "This is line 5" and the output is: "line_2: This is line5 
line_1: This is line0
line_3: This is line2"