# compare two files making abstraction of a pattern but display it

Tags: sed, awk, compare, diff

I want to compare two file using diff or soemthing else. Each line on the file starts with "line_x".
File:

```
line_1: This is line1
line_2: This is line2

....
```

I want to compare the files without the line_x. Something like this:

> diff <(sed '/line/,/:/g' diff1) <(sed '/line/,/:/g' diff2)

But wen i print the differences I want to insert the exact line_x that is different.
It is possible with awk or something else to do that?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you posting this [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047130/extract-different-lines-from-files-using-bash) and [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048420/diff-ignore-certain-pattern-in-the-file)?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
awk -f cmp.awk file1.txt file2.txt
```

where `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` are your input files and `cmp.awk` is

```
NR==FNR {
    $1=""
    b[FNR]=$0
    next
}
{
    $1=""
    if ($0!=b[FNR]) {
        printf "Line: %d\n", FNR
        printf "  File 1: %s\n", b[FNR]
        printf "  File 2: %s\n", $0
    }
}
```

if the lines in the two files are not sorted, you could try:

```
NR==FNR {
    a=$1;   $1=""
    b[a]=$0
    next
}
{
    a=$1; $1=""
    if ($0!=b[a]) {
        printf "%s\n", a
        printf "  File 1: %s\n", b[a]
        printf "  File 2: %s\n", $0
    }
}
```